# Qt non rectangular window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to create a non rectangular window with Qt.

Like this:

```
           ______________________
          |                      |
    ______|                      |
  /                              |
 /                               |
|                                |
|                                |
 \                               |
  \_______                       |
          |                      |
          |                      |
          |                      |
          |______________________|
```

With the transparent parts actually being click through to the non-Qt window below.

The only way I have found to get this done is: `window->setMask(complex_region);`

But that seems pretty hacky, especially since I now need to know the sizes of window parts both in the C++ and qml.

Ideally I would like to tell Qt to just not render fully transparent stuff.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your theory, that using `setMask` which is to set a mask, to be hacky? And since you are the one to decide the mask, you should have knowledge of its size?

Comment: I consider it hacky in the sense that I define the way everything looks in qml and then I have to make sure that it actually does what I want in the C++ layer.
That means I have to know the size off the various components inside in both qml and C++ and it make resizing more complicated.

Comment: You may expose a `QObject` as context property. In this you have one property which holds a mask. So you have access to it from both QML and C++.

Comment: @Mathias see this project: https://github.com/CodeHuntersLab/CuriElements :P

Answer (score 1):

You can create a main widget and with qpainter you draw the design.  After all others widgets are inside the main widget. Finally, you add transparancy for the main widget and you have what you want.

Comment: Does this work, when you don't use widgets but QtQuick?

Comment: You can combine qml and c++ and i didn’t test with qtquick. But you create a main qwidget in c++ and you put your qml inside.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of what you mean? I am pretty new to Qt.

Comment: Instead of the usual routine in your `main.cpp` you can have a QtWidgets based application, that you feed with [`QQuickWidgets`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html) in which you load your qml. But this is what I would find *hacky*

Comment: Will this be better than the solution of *GrecKo* i.e. have the window to be transparent to clicks as well? Can you elaborate on how he has access to the dimensions of the region from within QML then?

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the `color` of the `Window` to `transparent` and set `flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint` works for me on macOS :

[image: non rectangular qml window]

Comment: I like this solution, but the benefit of using the mask is, that it ignores clicks outside the region. This does not work with the transparency.

Comment: This might be a (un)lucky coincidence. I vaguely remember that on macOS everything with full transparency (opacity=0) is not clickable / "click-trough". On Windows, it is opacity<5. So, this is an implicit OS feature, that might be unavailable on some platforms, e.g. Linux.

Comment: Yeah, on macOS, a click on the transparent area goes to the window below. Can't currently confirm for other platforms though.

Comment: Ok, I could not confirm it on Mac, have only tried it on Win7. @DanielS: *On Windows, it is opacity<5*? Opacity is in a range of 0 to 1 I thought... What do you mean with this?

Comment: @derM: The alpha channel is usually 8bit (ARGB / "#AARRGGBB"), and so it has the values 0...255. GDI32 makes the values 0...4 click-through, macOS only the value 0. (As I remember it from like ~7 years ago...)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't expect to see hex values. I was too focused on the property `opacity` which is in the range 0..1 - however I can't confirm that behavior. Even with `#00000000` I don't have a click-through experience in Win7. I don't know anything about GDI32 though.

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is, that you want to set the mask from QML, you can create a `QObject` that is accessible from QML to tunnel to the methods `setMask` and `mask` of the `QWindow`.

I have decided I will create this Object from within QML. The design might be improved, but it works, and shall outline the idea.

**exposemask.h**

```
#ifndef EXPOSEMASK_H
#define EXPOSEMASK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRegion>
#include <QWindow>

class ExposeMask : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QRegion mask READ mask WRITE setMask)

public:
    ExposeMask(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void setWindow(QWindow* win);
    // Little helper to get a region from a image in QML.
    Q_INVOKABLE QRegion regionFromImage(QString path);

    QRegion mask() const;

    void setMask(const QRegion &region);

private:
    QWindow* m_window;

};

#endif // EXPOSEMASK_H
```

**exposemask.cpp**

```
#include "exposemask.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QDebug>

ExposeMask::ExposeMask(QObject* parent)
        : QObject(parent)
        , m_window(nullptr)
{
}

QRegion ExposeMask::regionFromImage(QString path)
{
        QPixmap pix(path);
        return pix.mask();
}

QRegion ExposeMask::mask() const
{
    if (m_window != nullptr)
    {
        return m_window->mask();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "No Window Set";
    }
}

void ExposeMask::setMask(const QRegion &region)
{
    m_window->setMask(region);
}

void ExposeMask::setWindow(QWindow* win) { m_window = win; }
```

In **main.cpp -> `int main([...])`**

```
qmlRegisterType<ExposeMask>("ExposeMask", 1, 0, "ExposeMask");
```

In **main.qml**

```
ExposeMask {
    // I need to do it "onCompleted" for I need to set the window first...
    // You can change this by having the region as a member, exposing the window as property e.t.c
    Component.onCompleted: {
        setWindow(appwindow)
        mask = regionFromImage("mask.png")
    }
}
```

For handling the shapes it might be easier, if you have multiple windows with the right shape. So in the case of your drawing I would use two windows, where one is rectangular, and only the protuberance needs to be masked. So individual changes of their sizes are easier to calculate.

Also, if the calculations become complex, consider adding well suited helper functions to the exposed object in C++

Comment: Just from the beginning: I usually fail when I try to have classes without header files. As I don't need that knowledge for production code, I never had enough motivation to learn that.